# How to see the source codes on eclipse?

Tags: java

I am trying to see the java.lang and java.util classes on eclipse, but I can see all the classes and the methods on the left side but I have a problem of viewing the method implementations.  It looks like something is wrong. It says the source attachment does not contain the source file Class.class(someother.class). You can change the source attachment by clicking change attached source below.
how could I fix this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to see the bytecodes use `javap -c`.

Comment: (It's spelled "Eclipse".  And if you don't want bytecodes you shouldn't tag `bytecode`.)

Answer (score 1):

By downloading (and attaching) the source to the version of the JDK you are using. You won't see byte codes just source code. For Java 7, one possible resource is the open source [jdk7src](http://jdk7src.sourceforge.net/).